# Show Exception Box

Tags: c#, exception

I am throwing an exception in c# in some cases. The problem is, that I want to show the exception in a box like this (no MessageBox):

[image]

But so far the Program is only crashing, after the exception is throwed. I throw the exception like this:

```
throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a JIT(Just In Time) Exception box, I'm not quite sure how you would display it tho... Perhaps take a look here about halfway down the page to enable JIT. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx

Comment: Thank you Astro. I hadn't known, that this box comes directly from windows. I think that the problem is, that I am programming with WPF and WPF probably don't show this box automaticly, if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

.NET does not have a built-in feature that shows exception in a nice box. You need to write code that captures exception and displays it.

Effort is needed but you have a chance to show it in the way you want.

Comment: Hi Kirill Kobelev. That's interesting, because I know 100percently that some of my other programms show this box if an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Ahrtaler And they probably have some code that catches the exceptions and displays them in a user friendly way.

Comment: @mason If they have something like this I would know that because I wrote them. :D Astro was right it's the Just-in-Time Exception box but in an WPF applications it isn't used that way that I prefere. Because that I now have writen the class that displays the Exception in the way I want to.

Comment: There are tons of libraries, frameworks, platforms, etc that are built on top of .NET. Some of them definitely have features for displaying exceptions. My point is that there is no .NET wide feature for doing that. This is kind of sad but this is so.

Comment: @Ahrtaler I didn't say it was your code. The point is, there is somewhere in the code that catches it and displays it properly. That's really all you have to do, and it gives your complete control over the look and feel of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guy now I tried to throw an exception with WPF and WindowsForms.
If you throw an exception in WPF this box opens:

[image: Sorry, the text is written in german.]

After this a seccond box appears:

[image: Sorry, the text is written in german.]

But if you thrown an exception in an WindowsForms application the following box appears:

[image: Sorry, the text is written in german.]

It is not important, if you write in c# or VB. The main different is, that the Box in WindowsForms allows the user to continue the programm. The Box in WPF don't allows the user to continue the programm. But it allows the user to send informations somewhere. But I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a class that displays the Exceptions. Ofcourse you have to catch them before you can display them.

Here is the download link: https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?waid=242925&aid=1198129